# Did all the tribes listen to their leaders in the sin of the spies?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shevatim-12-tribes, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

Why did the tribes of Ephraim and Yehuda not listen to their respective leaders, Yehoshua bin Nun and Kalev ben Yefuneh in the sin on the spies? (See [Numbers 13:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9941#v=2), which says they were leaders.)

It seems that from the fact the whole generation died out, except for the two leaders mentioned above, everyone else was punished for the sin, including those two tribes.

Comment: I think it was simply a question that they were outnumbered 10 to 2, and everyone just followed the majority opinion, without necessarily listening to their own tribal leaders. There also may have been a sense of "peer pressure". If a group of your friends from other tribes (I'm sure people had inter-tyribale friendships) put fear into you, and their reasoning sounded sensible, you would probably follow them, as well, unless you were so self-disciplined to be able to do your own thing and realize that the majority was wrong.

Comment: I seem to recall moments in the Torah where the people of each tribe listened to its leader. For example, when Moshe called out "Mi LeHashem Elai" all of the tribe of Levi came to him. IIRC there are other examples of this. That would make this case the exception @DanF